# SQL Check is there different records in table

Tags: sql

I want to check if there are any different records in my table. I have a `sales` table and in this table I have 2 records for same product so actually this salesman doesn't sale more than one product. I need a `select` query to check salesmen who sell more than 1 (different) product.

Table name `SALES` -- columns `sales_id`, `salesman_name`, `product,name`, `quantity`

Need only show salesman names.

[Example data and expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEhGK.png)

Comment: Hi Hikmet, which dbms you using?

Comment: would please show some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT <Field Name>)` for what you want. (same for `sqlserver`, `MySQL` and `Oracle`)
Check this query:

```
SELECT salesman_name
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT product) ProductCount
FROM Sales
GROUP BY salesman_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product) >1
```

Comment: Hi @ZulqarnainJalil, it's because Hikmet wanted to see only if different products has more then one for each sales person. If I don't use DISTINCT, the query will calculate same products as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SALES
WHERE salesman_name IN (
  SELECT 
    salesman_name
  FROM SALES
  GROUP BY product
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select salesman_name
from sales
group by salesman_name
having min(product) <> max(product);
```

If you want the original rows use `exists`:

```
select s.*
from sales s
where exists (select 1
              from sales s2
              where s2.salesman_name = s.salesman_name and
                    s2.product <> s.product
             );
```

With an index on `sales(salesman_name, product)`, this should be the fastest way to get the original rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    salesman_name,product,COUNT(*)
FROM
    SALES
GROUP BY
    salesman_name,product
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```